# bash parameter expansion changes original string

Tags: bash, shell

I have inherited a shell script. One of the things it does is parsing of a list of filenames. For every filename in the list it does following command:

```
fs_item="`echo ${fs_item%/}`"
```

This command (a part from doing it's job which in this case, I think, is to remove everything after last slash) replaces spaces in filename with one space:

```
in:  aa bbbb              ccc
out: aa bbbb ccc
```

From this point filename is broken.

So, the question is: can I somehow tell bash not to replace spaces?

Comment: This is unclear to me.. if you don't want the line fs_item="`echo ${fs_item%/}`" to replace spaces, then remove that line.

Comment: I have added a comment. The command is there for some other reason, bot to replace spaces

Comment: ${foo%/} just removes a trailing slash if there is one.  If there are multiple trailing slashes, it removes just the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the echo really necessary?  You could simply remove it:

```
fs_item="${fs_item%/}"
```

If your actual problem is something different, and you cannot get rid of the echo (or some other command invocation), adding some quotes should work:

```
fs_item="`echo \"${fs_item%/}\"`"
```

The spaces vanish when running the backticked `echo` command.  The internal field separator includes the space character, so words separated by a sequence of one or more spaces will be passed as separate arguments to `echo`.  Then, echo just prints it's arguments separated by a single space.

Since we're on the internal field separator subject, changing the IFS should also work (but usually has other possibly undesirable effects elsewhere in your script):

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

This sets the internal field separator to the newline character.  After this, the spaces are no longer considered to be separators for lists.  The echo command will receive just one argument (unless you have file names with the newline character in them) and spaces will stay intact.

Comment: Adding quotes just adds an additional layer of obfuscation.  The echo needs to be purged.

Comment: Based on comments in the original question I suspect the actual problem apparently may not be possible to simplify like that.  But fair enough, I'll mention this in my post as well.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the backticks and the echo command. It is worse than useless in this situation because it adds nothing, and causes the problem you are trying to solve here.

```
fs_item="${fs_item%/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IFS to something else, e.g. IFS=","